# PHPExcel, не выносит в отчет excel даные из БД, именно которые написаны кириллицей

Tags: php, phpexcel

Формируется отчет excel в PHP с помощью библиотеки PHPExcel, кодировка всех таблиц БД - UTF-8 , но самой БД все же windows-1251 ...

```
    <?php
require_once('PHPExcel.php');
require_once('PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php');
require_once('config.php');

$dbc = mysqli_connect($_HOST, $_USERNAME, $_PASSWORD, $_NAME_DB );
 $query = "SELECT * FROM rpk_02_pto WHERE id_pto = 1 ";

$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data) ;

   // public $_id_pto = 0;
$_ABC = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL');
$fields = array(
            'first_name', //2
            'name', //3
            'patronymic', //4                       
            'date_birth', //5
            'sex', //6
            'id_code_jobs', //7
            'ped_work',
            'id_academic_code', //8
            'id_code_qual_cat', //9
            'id_qualif_rank', //10
            'id_code_object', //11
            'id_code_object_dop', //12
            'teaching_experience', //13
            'officio_experience', //14
            'higher_pedagogical_education', //15
            'higher_education_more', //16
            'sec_pedagogical_education', //17
            'sec_education_more', //18
            'overall_average', //19
            'year_probation', //20
            'id_code_educ_inst', //21
            'year_last_training', //22
            'id_specialty_code', //23
            'retraining_year', //24
            'retraining_enrolled_current_year', //25
            'code_educ_specialty_group', //26
            'year_training_profile_specialty', //27
            'id_note'); //29

$xls = new PHPExcel();
// Устанавливаем индекс активного листа
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Получаем активный лист
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
// Подписываем лист
$sheet->setTitle('РПК02');


for($i=0;$i!=28;$i++)
{
    $sheet->getColumnDimension($_ABC[$i])->setWidth(10);
}
        $sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(15);
        $sheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(15);
        $sheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(15);
        $sheet->getColumnDimension('Z')->setWidth(20);


        $sheet->mergeCells('A1:A3');
        $sheet->mergeCells('B1:D1');
        $sheet->mergeCells('B2:B3');
        ...


 $sheet->setCellValue('A5', $row['name']); //не выводится так как кириллица(вообще пустая ячейка)
 $sheet->setCellValue('D5', $row['sex']); //    тут и
 $sheet->setCellValue('B5', $row['id_code_jobs']); // тут выводятся как и положены цифры



        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Код учреждения образования');
        $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Сотрудники');
        $sheet->setCellValue('B2', 'Фамилия');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C2', 'Имя');
        $sheet->setCellValue('D2', 'Отчество');
       ...


        $sheet->setCellValue('E5', '8с');
        $sheet->setCellValue('F5', '1ц');
        $sheet->setCellValue('G5', '3ц');
        $sheet->setCellValue('H5', '1ц');
        ...


        $sheet->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setTextRotation(90);
        $sheet->getStyle('B2')->getAlignment()->setTextRotation(90);
        $sheet->getStyle('C2')->getAlignment()->setTextRotation(90);
        ...


        // устанавливаем авто подбор высоты 
        $sheet->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
        $sheet->getRowDimension(2)->setRowHeight(-1);
        $sheet->getRowDimension(3)->setRowHeight(-1);


        // и авто перенос текста
        $sheet->getStyle('A1:AC1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        $sheet->getStyle('A2:AC2')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        $sheet->getStyle('A3:AC3')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

        $sheet->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(100);
        $sheet->getRowDimension(2)->setRowHeight(30);
        $sheet->getRowDimension(3)->setRowHeight(90);



      for($i = 0; $i < 29; ++$i)

        {

             $sheet->setCellValue($_ABC[$i] . '4', $i+1);
        }



 header ( "Expires: Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT" );
 header ( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT" );
 header ( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
 header ( "Pragma: no-cache" );
 header ( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
 header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.xls" );


 $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($xls);
 $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Я ставил перед запросом `mysql_set_charset("UTF-8");` - не помогло, что вообще можно сделать, чтоб отобразилось? :3

Comment: в общем всю БД перевел в кодировку  utf8_general_ci (и так все таблицы были в этой кодировке, погоды не сыграет по идее..), в общем это тоже не помогло

Answer (score 1):

iconv значений в нужную кодировку (в phpEXcell нужен utf8).

```
iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $str2);
```

Comment: $str2 = $row['name'];
iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $str2);
 $sheet->setCellValue('A5', $str2 );   //не помогло...

Comment: А вот тут 

>> $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Код учреждения образования');

выводится кириллица?

Comment: да, шапка отчета формируется чудесно, все русские символы, которые напрямую с кода, выводятся, но из БД только цифры...

Comment: Значит  не всё сделал с кодировкой. mysqli_set_charset("UTF-8", $dbc) после подключения.
Определи кодировку вывода из БД http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: мне в свое время помогло iconv